# sleep function not working

Tags: android, andengine

I want to show 1 to 100 in a changeable text. I like to use sleep()function so that it looks like that it is increasing form 1 to 100. my code is

```
for(int i= 0;i<100;i++) {
    scorelevel.setText(String.valueOf(i));
    try{
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it did not show properly. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not show properly" ?

Comment: use Asynctask .... for you knowledge try with a larger time like 4 sec 4000 in sleep ...1 sec loos to less..

Comment: when the UI thread sleeps, the UI elements do not respond to touch events, e.g. the user will think that your app freezes. And you don't want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't block UI thread, use `AsyncTask` instead

Comment: also guessing you are calling that in onStart or onCreate methods if so then it isn't designed to work.

Comment: Thank you user956030. but how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Timer` and `TimerTask` to perform any time based task.

Answer (score 0):

You can start counter using  [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)  to update textView as:

```
private boolean mClockRunning=false;
private int millisUntilFinished=0;
public void myThread(){
            Thread th=new Thread(){
             @Override
             public void run(){
              try
              {
               while(mClockRunning)
               {
               Thread.sleep(1000L);// set time here for refresh time in textview
               YourCurrentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if(mClockRunning)
                     {
                     if(millisUntilFinished==100)
               {
               mClockRunning=false;
               millisUntilFinished=0;
                }
                else
                {
               millisUntilFinished++;
               scorelevel.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));//update textview here

               }
             }

            };
          }
              }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             }
             }
            };
            th.start();
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `TimerTask` ([link](http://android.okhelp.cz/timer-simple-timertask-java-android-example/)), too.